# Combining corresponding dataframe column values in r

Tags: r, dataframe

I currently have the following dataframes:

```
> corr
          i4        i3        i2
i1 0.7965509 0.8198761 0.7941727
> newcor
   i4 i3 i2
i1  0  0  0
```

I would like to combine these dataframes into one dataframe that sorts the corr values from greatest to least from left to right and puts the corresponding newcor values in the following row so that the final result is:

```
> newcor
        i3        i4        i2
i1 0.8198761 0.7965509 0.7941727
i1 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
```

It is just a coincidence that all the values in the 2nd row are 0s, and they must lineup according to initial values in newcor.  For example in this case the first newcor would be:

```
> newcor
   i3 i4 i2
i1  0  0  0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
 corr1 <- corr[,order(-corr)]
 rbind(corr1, newcor[names(corr1)])
```

Or can be combined to a single line as @Frank suggested if the initial data columns are in the same order

```
 rbind(corr,newcor)[,order(-corr)]
```

Comment: Or `rbind(corr,newcor)[,order(-corr)]`

Comment: @Frank I guess that needs the assumption that the column names are the in the order in the initial dataset

Comment: @akrun that worked; however, the second row becomes named i11 as such: `> rbind(corr1, newcor[names(corr1)])
           i3        i4        i2
i1  0.8198761 0.7965509 0.7941727
i11 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000`  How can I make it so both of these rows have the same name always?  Thanks!

Comment: @costebk08 Row names in a data.frame must be distinct. If you were using a matrix, I guess that wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @costebk08 as Frank mentioned, it is a feature in data.frame.